# JavaScript showing/hiding pictures

Tags: javascript

First I will give you my code

```html
<ul>
  <li><a data-img="simon-pics" id="simon" href="#">Simon Cowell</a></li>
  <li><a data-img="bruce-pics" id="bruce" href="#">Bruce Willis</a></li>
  <li><a data-img="ben-pics" id="ben" href="#">Ben Carson</a></li>
</ul>

<img class="hide" id="simon-pics" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/aa/Simon_Cowell_in_December_2011.jpg">
<img class="hide" id="bruce-pics" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/03/Bruce_Willis_by_Gage_Skidmore.jpg">
<img class="hide" id="ben-pics" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f1/Ben_Carson_by_Skidmore_with_lighting_correction.jpg/220px-Ben_Carson_by_Skidmore_with_lighting_correction.jpg" alt="">
```

That is my HTML code and this is my CSS

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block
}
```

So my idea is when I click on the given list element - the corresponding picture to appear - and I succeed with that.

My problem is that I want when there are more than 2 pictures already opened, my code to automatically closes one of the already opened one's.

```js
var simon = document.getElementById("simon")
var bruce = document.getElementById("bruce")
var ben = document.getElementById("ben")

simon.addEventListener("click", show)
bruce.addEventListener("click", show)
ben.addEventListener("click", show)

function show() {
    let images = document.querySelectorAll("img")
    /* Array.prototype.forEach.call(images, function (x){
        x.className = "hide"
    })*/

    let id = this.attributes["data-img"].value
    let imgId = document.getElementById(id)

    if (imgId.className === "hide") {
        imgId.className = "show"
    } else {
        imgId.className = "hide"
    }

    //till here everything is OK
    let classes = document.querySelectorAll(".show")
    let full = []
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(classes, function (x) {
        full.push(x)
    })

    /*for(let i = 0; i<classes.length; i++){
    full.push(classes[i])

    }*/

    if (full.length > 2) {
        full[1].className = "hide"
        full.shift()
        console.log(full[0].id)
    }
}
```

And this code works(kind of) - but after a few successful rounds - it stops working - like i am not able to open the third picture and therefore close one of the existing one's

Comment: where is your html for your images and list?

Comment: if you're new to javascript use `var` instead of  `let` to avoid scope confusion

Comment: @Vivick How is this comment relevant to the question/problem? O.o

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all your show() method works fine on my computer. The only change that I made is to get the img element and assign the eventListener inside the window.onload function to avoid the risk of get an undefined value.

```
var simon;
var bruce;
var ben;

window.onload = function(){
simon = document.getElementById("simon")
bruce = document.getElementById("bruce")
ben = document.getElementById("ben")

simon.addEventListener("click", show)
bruce.addEventListener("click", show)
ben.addEventListener("click", show)
}
```

Comment: The idea is when i open more than 2 pictures - one of the pictures to be closed and the new one to show up. And that works as well - but try doing that 2 times. For example - open the first 2 pictures and then the 3-rd one - this time it will work! But then try to open the first/second - in that moment, it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution since you already have a data attribute on your elements. This works for es5. You can do some fancier stuff in es6 if you want.

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('imageHideShow');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener('click', show);
}

function show() {
  var ele = document.getElementById(this.dataset.img);

  if (ele.classList.contains('hide')) {
    var images = imagesShown();
    if (images.length === 2) {
      images[0].classList.remove('show');
      images[0].classList.add('hide');
    }
    ele.classList.remove('hide');
    ele.classList.add('show');
  } else {
    ele.classList.remove('show');
    ele.classList.add('hide');
  }
}

function imagesShown() {
  var images = document.getElementsByClassName('images');
  var returnValue = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var image = images[i];
    if (image.classList.contains('show')) {
      returnValue.push(image);
    }
  }
  return returnValue;
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a data-img="simon-pics" class="imageHideShow" href="#">Simon Cowell</a></li>
  <li><a data-img="bruce-pics" class="imageHideShow" href="#">Bruce Willis</a></li>
  <li><a data-img="ben-pics" class="imageHideShow" href="#">Ben Carson</a></li>
</ul>

<img class="hide images" id="simon-pics" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/aa/Simon_Cowell_in_December_2011.jpg">
<img class="hide images" id="bruce-pics" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/03/Bruce_Willis_by_Gage_Skidmore.jpg">
<img class="hide images" id="ben-pics" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f1/Ben_Carson_by_Skidmore_with_lighting_correction.jpg/220px-Ben_Carson_by_Skidmore_with_lighting_correction.jpg" alt="">
```

Comment: My problem is that I want when there are more than 2 pictures already opened, my code to automatically closes one of the already opened one's.

Comment: Please notice `<>` icon. You can add *HTML/CSS/JS* code and make it executable.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

#### Logic:

- Create a variable that will hold list of images that are visible.
- On click of `a`, fetch necessary element id from data attribute.
- Now check if this exists in current list. If not, add it to top.
- Now check if length is greater than `2`, pop last element and hide this image.

**Note:** I'm using `unshift` to add and `pop` to remove. This is to create a stack like structure. You can altternatively use `.push` to add and `.splice(0,1)` to remove as well.

**[Sample Code](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/f4e0cd9z/1/)**

```js
var visibleImages = [];

function registerEvents() {
  var els = document.querySelectorAll('li a');
  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].addEventListener('click', handleClick);
  }
}

function handleClick() {
  var imgId = this.getAttribute('data-img');
  addIDtoList(imgId)
  showImage(imgId)
  return false;
}

function addIDtoList(id) {
  if (visibleImages.indexOf(id) < 0)
    visibleImages.unshift(id);

  if (visibleImages.length > 2)
    hideImage(visibleImages.pop())
}

function showImage(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).classList.remove('hide');
}

function hideImage(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).classList.add('hide');
}

registerEvents();
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block
}

img {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a data-img="simon-pics" id="simon" href="#">Simon Cowell</a></li>
  <li><a data-img="bruce-pics" id="bruce" href="#">Bruce Willis</a></li>
  <li><a data-img="ben-pics" id="ben" href="#">Ben Carson</a></li>
</ul>

<img class="hide" id="simon-pics" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/aa/Simon_Cowell_in_December_2011.jpg">
<img class="hide" id="bruce-pics" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/03/Bruce_Willis_by_Gage_Skidmore.jpg">
<img class="hide" id="ben-pics" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f1/Ben_Carson_by_Skidmore_with_lighting_correction.jpg/220px-Ben_Carson_by_Skidmore_with_lighting_correction.jpg" alt="">
```

Comment: Thank you So much!!